# Saving parquet files without hadoop

Tags: java, scala, avro, parquet

I want to store some Java/Scala objects as records in Parquet format, and I'm currently using [parquet-avro](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-avro) and the [`AvroParquetWriter`](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/avro/AvroParquetWriter.java) class for this purpose. This works fine, but it is very coupled to Hadoop and it's file system implementation(s). Instead, I would like to somehow get the raw binary data of the files (preferably, but not absolutely necessary, in a streaming fashion) and handle the writing of the files "manually", due to the nature of the framework I'm integrating with. Has anyone been able to achieve something like this?

Comment: Possibly [this](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/format/Util.java)

Comment: It does seem to be some ongoing work to resolve this, with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1142. So hopefully, with the release of 1.10 of the java libraries, this will become much easier.